# Kafka upgrade : Need to specify inter.broker.protocol.version when upgraded?

Tags: apache-kafka

I upgraded my Kafka cluster from `1.1.0` to `2.3.0` following those steps :
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_3_0

Everything went fine ( and I did not have to change the message format version). 
I totally understand why we should set the `inter.broker.protocol.version` to `1.1` when doing the first rolling restart, but I don't get why we should then set it again to `2.3` value afterwards.

I mean we can just remove the  `inter.broker.protocol.version` parameter from `server.properties` and it should be fine. Why `2.3` brokers should know that they should use `2.3` protocol version, is this not the protocol by default ?

Comment: In the first step, you had to set `inter.broker.protocol.version=CURRENT_KAFKA_VERSION` (i.e. 1.1). Once your upgrade is successful, you need to update the `inter.broker.protocol.version` to the latest version and make all the brokers aware that the latest protocol version should be used when communicating with other brokers in the cluster.

Comment: Yes I know, but restarting a broker without putting the parameter will let it use the last version no ? If you don't specify the ```inter.broker.protocol.version```, the ```2.3.0``` binary will use ```2.3.0``` protocol version no ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question the first time I upgraded my kafka cluster.  However the next time I upgraded I didnt have to set the inter.broker.protocol.version before I installed the new binary because it was already there. My thought is that it doesnt hurt anything and it removes any question about what inter.broker.protocol.version is being used on any broker that I am logged on to.

Answer (score 1):

In the first step, you had to set `inter.broker.protocol.version=CURRENT_KAFKA_VERSION`. In your case, this was `inter.broker.protocol.version=1.1`. Once your upgrade is successful, you need to update the `inter.broker.protocol.version` to the latest version (i.e. `2.3`) and finally restart all the brokers to apply this configuration and make all the brokers aware that the latest protocol version should be used when communicating with other brokers in the cluster.

Once you have changed the `inter.broker.protocol.version` to `2.3` and restarted all Kafka Brokers, then this parameter is not required anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but again, what the point of specifying the ```inter.broker.protocol.version``` to make them use ```2.3```, if not specifying it means they should use ```2.3``` ?

Comment: "They" probably want you to be safe in terms of "i can downgrade if I need to". Let's say you run Kafka as Docker containers and accidentally use the "latest" tag instead of a fixed version. Then you might perform an upgrade with all the benefits and risks. If now the new version has a critical bug and you did not specify the broker protocol version, you're in serious trouble. 

So "Better safe than sorry" is my guess why you are forced to set it.